# Updating the Sheet data on refresh (React + Fortune-Sheets component)

Tags: reactjs, excel, spreadsheet

I am using fortune-sheets, a spreadsheet component for react. My goal here is to simply input some data to a spreadsheet and render the saved data back on refresh. Here is the code:

```
import { Workbook } from "@fortune-sheet/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Sheet = () => {
 const [workbookData, setWorkbookData] = useState(null);

 const settings = {
    data: [{ name: 'Sheet1', celldata: [{ r: 0, c: 0, v: null }] }], // sheet data
    //OnChange, set the workbookData and save it
    onChange: (data) => {
      setWorkbookData(data);
      localStorage.setItem('workbookData', JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    // More other settings...
 }

 //On Refresh, render the saved data from local storage
 useEffect(() => {
    const savedData = localStorage.getItem('workbookData');
    if (savedData) {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(savedData);
      setWorkbookData(parsedData);
    }
  }, []);

  // This useEffect will run whenever workbookData changes and log its value
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("workbookData has been updated:", workbookData);
  }, [workbookData]);

 return (
    <div className="containerSheet">
      <Workbook {...settings} />
    </div>
 );
};

export default Sheet;
```

[image: four logs]

As shown above, the goal is store it in the localStorage and then update the value on refresh. In the console, when the page is refreshed with some user input, the workbookData is logged in four times, the first two as:

*workbookData has been updated: null*

The third log has an object instead of a null. This has the saved data (input data 'test' by the user) in local storage.

[image: third log 1]

Data input by the user:

[image: third log 2]

However, on the fourth log it completely disappears. I don't understand why.

[image: fourth log]

[Here is the documentation link.](https://ruilisi.github.io/fortune-sheet-docs/)

Read the above, yet unable to understand how I can fix this problem...

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem myself. When you initialize the Workbook, it takes `celldata` to render the data. Once it initializes it changes the shown data to a property called `data`. What you need to do is when you save your `workbookData`, add a property called `celldata` which has the `data` so whenever it intializes it calls `celldata`.
[Related Link](https://ruilisi.github.io/fortune-sheet-docs/guide/sheet.html#celldata)

I'm currently dealing with that it wont accept `celldata` to be the same as `data` because they have a diferent format, so I'm trying to transform it.
For the moment this code has worked for me, but i think it has bugs, i hope it helps you anyway

```
    const formatSheet = (sheet: Sheet) => {
    //Al momento de cargar los datos en la planilla se tienen que enviar como celldata con otro formato
    //https://ruilisi.github.io/fortune-sheet-docs/guide/sheet.html#celldata

    sheet.celldata = sheet.celldata || [];

    sheet.data?.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
      row.forEach((cell, columnIndex) => {
        sheet.celldata?.push({
          r: rowIndex,
          c: columnIndex,
          v: cell,
        });
      });
    });
    delete sheet.data;
  };
```

edit: I was having trouble with typescript. It turns out that the code was right, but it transform empty `data` cells to `celldata` with the object `{r:"X", c:"Y", v: null}` and in my case where i had a default `celldata` in a local file, that format of object is invalid, `v` MUST have something, or the whole object shouldn't be there. It must be `{r:"X", c:"Y", v:{...}}`, other way, Typescript will complain.